# Converting String to InputStream, and OutputStream to String back again

Tags: java, string, inputstream, outputstream

I am trying to do such conversions, but i have a little problem.

Let's say i have a following String:

```
String in = "1234567890123456";
```

Then I convert it to ByteArrayInputStream like this:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(in.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

I also have:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

Then I do my encryption:

```
ch.encrypt(bais, baos);
```

So now I have my "output" in `baos`. When i do such thing:

```
byte[] b2 = baos.toByteArray();
int[] i2 = toUnsignedIntArray(b2);
writeIntegersAsHex(i2);
```

where (I know it is not the most elegant way but it's only for testing):

```
 public static void writeIntegersAsHex(int[] integers) {
    int height = integers.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(integers[i]) + ",");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

I get such output:

```
d1,68,a0,46,32,37,25,64,67,71,17,df,ee,ef,2,12,
```

And that output is correct, because when I process file that contains the same string as `in` that output is the same. But I can't get a proper string from `baos`.

Please don't ask me why am i doing it this way, because it was not my call. I am a student and this is one of the excersises.

The algorithm (btw it's aes128) works ok, with files but i can't get string to inputstream and outputstream to string work properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I can't get a proper string from baos.

At this point your output is just arbitrary binary data. It's not encoded text - it's just a bunch of bits.

To convert that to a sensible string which will let you convert it back to the original bytes, you should probably use either hex or base64. There's a [public domain base64 library](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) which works well in my experience, or plenty of other alternatives (for both base64 and hex).

Comment: OK i get it, could you post me some example?

Comment: @cichy202: You've already got the data as a byte array, so just use `String text = Base64.encodeBytes(b2);`

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String in = "1234567890123456";
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(in.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int i;
        while ( ( i = bais.read() ) != -1  ){
            baos.write(i);
            baos.flush();
             }

        System.out.print(baos.toString());
    }
```